# php registration do not push to db issue

Tags: php, pdo, registration

I've got 2 classes - `db.class.php` and `user.class.php`. Within second one I have 2 methods associated with registration - `register` and `registerValidation`. `db` file is responsible for specifying db credentials and initializing connection. I do not really want to pollute my post so I will only give you db code as a [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d06cfa418236ea46a6761d0b7b0d5f37) because I don't really think that the problem lays there.

The code of `register` method and `validation` method is:

```
<?php

require_once 'token.php';

class User
{
    //db and table name
    private $conn;
    private $table_name = "users";

    // constructor with $db as database connection
    public function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    public function registerValidation($nick,$email,$password)
    {
        if(
            (strlen($nick) < 5 || strlen($nick) > 20) ||
            (strlen($email) < 3 || strlen($email) > 100) ||
            (strlen($password) < 6 || strlen($password) > 50)
        )
        {
            //$error = 'nick or email or password is wrong length';
            //echo json_encode($error);
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            // query to check if email already exists
            $query = "
                SELECT 
                  * 
                FROM 
                  " . $this->table_name . " 
                WHERE 
                  id = ?
                  OR
                  email = ?
              ";

            // prepare query statement
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

            // bind params
            $stmt->bindParam(1, $nick);
            $stmt->bindParam(2, $email);

            // execute query
            $stmt->execute();

            //count if there is same
            $num = $stmt->rowCount();

            if ($num > 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    public function register($nick,$email,$password)
    {
        try
        {
            $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            $query = "
                INSERT INTO
                  users(user, user, user) 
                VALUES
                  (?, ?, ?)";

            // prepare query statement
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

            //bind values from user
            $stmt->bindparam(1, $nick);
            $stmt->bindparam(2, $email);
            $stmt->bindparam(3, $password);

            $stmt->execute();

            return $stmt;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

I also have file `doRegister.php` which is some kind of endpoint for client side:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if(!empty($_POST['nick'])
        && !empty($_POST['email'])
        && !empty($_POST['password']))
    {
        // instantiate database
        require_once '../config/database.php';
        $database = new Database();
        $db = $database->getConnection();

        require_once '../classes/user.php';
        $user = new User($db);

        if($user->registerValidation($_POST['nick'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['password']))
        {
            $user->register($_POST['nick'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['password']);
            http_response_code(201);
        }
        else
        {
            http_response_code(400);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        http_response_code(400);
    }
}
else
{
    http_response_code(400);
}
```

When I send http POST request via postman I get `201(created)` but when I go to `localhost/phpmyadmin` after that, there is no new record inside user table in my mysql db. Why?

[image: 201 created via postman]
[image: no results in db]

Comment: Is the column names like (user, user, user) in `register($nick,$email,$password)` function

Comment: No it is id, nick, email, password as you can see on the second screenshot.

Comment: In the `register` function, also have a check to see if the insert query was successful

Comment: Also why are the columns,  user,  user user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `register` function is definitely returning false on execution of the `insert` statement. Also it looks like the columns are wrong.

```
        $query = "
            INSERT INTO
              users(nick, email , password) 
            VALUES
              (?, ?, ?)";

#before returning true or false do a check on execute()
return $stmt->execute() === true ?  true  : false;
```

Also before returning the header 201, do a check on the `register` function to verify that it was true and not false..